# Unable to find EOCD signature when generating signed apk

Tags: android, apk

I can run my application from android studio, but when I try to generate signed apk with a key that used to work, I get this error "Unable to find EOCD signature"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was already a generated debug apk. After I deleted it it worked.